# $F[[T]] \times F[[1/T]]$, fundamental domain.

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $p$ be a prime number. Here is a [link](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/210729/ft-times-f1-t-fundamental-domain-show-compactness) which shows how to see that $$(\mathbb{F}_p((T)) \times \mathbb{F}_p((1/T)))/\mathbb{F}_p[T, 1/T]$$is compact using an adelic result. (Here $\mathbb{F}_p[T, 1/T]$ is embedded in $\mathbb{F}_p((T)) \times \mathbb{F}_p((1/T))$ diagonally.) My question is, does anyone know of a more elementary way to show this using fundamental domains?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\FF}{\mathbb{F}}$
Given $a=\sum_{k} a_k T^k \in \FF_p((T))$ and $b = \sum_{r} b_r T^{-r}\in \FF_p((1/T))$, there's a unique element $c=\sum_{n}c_k T^k \in \FF_p[T,1/T]$ such that $a_k - c_k =0$ for $k < 0$ and $b_r - c_{-r}= 0$ for $r \leq 0$. This makes it possible to identify the quotient with $\prod_{n\in \mathbb{Z}} \FF_p$ by sending $(a,b)$ to $(a_n - b_{-n})_n$. This infinite product is compact by Tychonoff's theorem.

A fundamental domain consists of $(a,b)$ with $a_k = 0$ for $k<0$ and $b_r = 0$ for $r \leq 0$, or $\FF_p[[T]] \times (1/T)\FF_p[[1/T]]$